# PHP - Combine Arrays of different lengths

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, mapping, grouping

I have two arrays that I need to combine into a new arrays with keys taken from the array values.  The first array has SubLineItemId as Array(Key):

```
    $arr_sublineitems {
    ["e2a1b308-8895-41ce-9688-878c13b00c14"]=>
    {
        ["PurchaseOrderId"]=> "23c03079-d06e-4c5e-bebc-bfcdbfeea635"  // PurchaseOrderId:VendorId 1:N
        ["SubLineItemId"]=> "e2a1b308-8895-41ce-9688-878c13b00c14" // PurchaseOrderId:SublineItemId = 1:N 
        ["VendorId"]=> "24d84b89-ef9a-4347-95c0-d282fcf19b58" // PurchaseOrderId:VendorId = 1:1
        ["Quantity"]=> int(40)
        ["SellPrice"]=> float(131)
        ["FreightSell"]=> float(0)
        ["NetPrice"]=> float(121.8375)
        ["FreightNet"]=> float(0)
        ["Taxable"]=> bool(true)
        ["ProjectId"]=> "827c879c-8dd6-4738-85f8-c14da2c743b8"
        ["Total_Sell"]=> float(5240)
      }
    ...}
```

The second array has the PurchaseOrderId as Array(Key):

```
    $arr_filtered_po {
    ["23c03079-d06e-4c5e-bebc-bfcdbfeea635"]=> //PurchaseOrderId
      {
        ["VendorId"]=> "f9757947-18cc-4b2f-9c8d-722d5a4ba38c"  //VendorId:PONumber = 1:N
        ["PONumber"]=> "1211111-20" // PONumber:VendorId = 1:1
      }
    ...
    }
```

The desired result is grouped by PurchaseOrderId:VendorId with all SubLineItems associated with the PurchaseOrderId:VendorId combination:

```
    array(["23c03079-d06e-4c5e-bebc-bfcdbfeea635"] =>(  //PurchaseOrderId,
        ["VendorId"]=> "24d84b89-ef9a-4347-95c0-d282fcf19b58" {
           ["SubLineItemId"]=> "e2a1b308-8895-41ce-9688-878c13b00c14"{
           ["Quantity"]=> int(40)
           ["SellPrice"]=> float(131)
           ["FreightSell"]=> float(0)
           ["NetPrice"]=> float(121.8375)
           ["FreightNet"]=> float(0)
           ["Taxable"]=> bool(true)
           ["ProjectId"]=> "827c879c-8dd6-4738-85f8-c14da2c743b8"
           ["Total_Sell"]=> float(5240)
           ["PONumber"]=> "1211111-20
           },
         },
         {["SubLineItemId"]=> .... // for each PurchaseOrderId:VendorID => SubLineItemId's
         },
        ],

...
Next PurchaseOrderId...
```

There can be a multitude of PurchaseOrderId's, VendorId's, SubLineItemId's, etc.  I'm sure I have my braces off in the examples - this is making my head spin.

I've tried array_merge and array_combine using foreach $arr_sublineitems / $arr_filtered_po without the correct results.  I am trying to loop and just create a new array with the correct values, but having an issue collating the PurchaseOrderId:VendorId across numerous items in the arrays:

```
        foreach($arr_sublineitems as $item => $items)
            foreach($arr_filtered_po as $key => $value){
                $po_id = ($items['PurchaseOrderId']);
                unset ($items['PurchaseOrderId']);
                    $subline = $items['SubLineItemId'];
                    unset ($items['SubLineItemId']);
                    $arr_qbo[][$key][$subline] += $items;
            }
        }
```

Comment: It's not completely clear what you are after but the first thing you need to do is to know which is the main container and how we identify it... it seems that the main key for your issue is the PurchaseOrderId right? in which array do this key only appear one time? or does it appear more than once in both?

Comment: What I am going at is that you need to loop through the array with the key and inside the loop you check with if statements if the PurchaseOrderId is the same you add the wanted values ... the question is which array is in the first loop and which is in the 2nd... the first array in the loop should be the one that supplies the main key-value of the new array we shall create.

Comment: @Shlomtzion - PurchaseOrderId appears in both arrays, but it is the key for $arr_filtered_po.  So I need the outer loop to be $arr_filtered_po, then loop through $arr_sublineitems and to check for the same PurchaseOrderId and add sublineitems if found.

Comment: So that should be the first array we loop in ... while in this loop we start looping the other array using the first key as an if ($1stArraykey == $2ndarrVal['PurchaseOrderId']) then we put all our wanted values in a new array $newArray[$key][$2ndarrVal['SubLineItemId']] = $2ndarrVal; something like that...

Comment: Please do not yatta-yatta your input data.  This [mcve] is Unclear.  Please strip all irrelevant data from your sample data to reduce the "noise".

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($arr_filtered_po as $po => $poid) {
    foreach ($arr_sublineitems as $item => $items) {
        if ($po == $items['PurchaseOrderId']) {
            $arr_po_list[] = [
                 'PurchaseOrderId' => $po, 
                 'VendorId' => [$items['VendorId']],                                                                                     
                 'SubLineItemId' => [$items['SubLineItemId']] = [
                     'ProjectId' => $project_id,
                     'Quantity' => $items['Quantity'],
                     'SellPrice' => $items['SellPrice'],
                     'FreightSell' => $items['FreightSell'],
                     'NetPrice' => $items['NetPrice'],
                     'FreightNet' => $items['FreightNet'],
                     'Taxable' => $items['Taxable'],
                     'Total_Sell' => $items['SellPrice'] * $items['Quantity']
                ]
            ];
        }
    }
}
```